# Azure table Storage - Table service Query to retrieve and return 10 entities till last entity

Tags: azure, entity-framework, linq, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have a table storage table which has more than 2000 entities. Performing Table service query execution to fetch all 2000 entities in one go is taking time. So I was trying to use LINQ Take operator but it is returning only 10 entities. What should be done to fetch and return the next 10 entities till all 2000 entities?

```
      var query = (from entity in context.CreateQuery<Customer>("FirstTenEntities")  
             select entity).Take(10);
```

Comment: have you tried pagination?

Comment: Reopening the question as `skip` is not a supported LINQ operator with Azure Storage Tables.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide complete code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [segmented tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#retrieving-large-numbers-of-entities-from-a-query)

```
string filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Sales");
TableQuery<EmployeeEntity> employeeQuery = new TableQuery<EmployeeEntity>().Where(filter);
employeeQuery.TakeCount = 50;  

TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
do
{
    var employees = employeeTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented(employeeQuery, continuationToken);
    foreach (var emp in employees)
    {
        // ...
    }
    
    continuationToken = employees.ContinuationToken;
} while (continuationToken != null);
```

That way if you are returning data to the client you will need to return this token back so you can fetch next batch

Comment: Thanks @Vova Bilyachat. Can you provide a sample how to make a call from client end jquery ajax using token and how it should be handled here in C#